# Reducing space between boxes aligned vertically in R shiny using css

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Please refer to the snapshot, The three boxes in the R shiny dashboard are displayed using the below script. I wish to reduce the space completely between the above two boxes and the lower box, I want the necessary command to include in my tags$head. Please help and thanks.

```
box(title = "",status = "primary",solidHeader = T,height = "287",width = "6", plotlyOutput("user_hist")),
box(title = "User Activity Mapping", status = "primary",height = "287" ,width = "6",solidHeader = T,plotlyOutput("sankey_plot",height = "216")),
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div.col-sm-12 {padding:1px}; float:up;"))),
box( title = "Case Details", status = "primary", height = "169",width = "12",solidHeader = T,dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
```

[image: box space reduction]

Comment: Maybe `tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div.col-sm-6 {margin-bottom: -20px;}"))), ; box(title = "",...)`

Comment: This is what solves the problem exactly, Thanks for your help though, I tried and did something myself, tags$head(tags$style(HTML("div.col-sm-12 {padding: 0px;margin-top: -20px;margin-right: -10px; };  ")))

Comment: If you solved the problem, you are encouraged to answer the question yourself.

Comment: is that sanky plot in box2?

Comment: Yes it is Hardik.